# How to get access to array in array json?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, api

I have to get access and parse the array in the json format. But the problem is that this array contains of another arrays.
This is my json file:[image]

Another version if you need [image]

Now I can not got access to the array resultA but how to got access to resultA[0]. This is the code that I now have  `

```
            if let resultsAnswer = jsons["resultA"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                print("got Result", resultsAnswer)
                self.Variants = []
                for result in resultsAnswer {
                    let variant = Variant()
                    variant.title = result["title"] as? String
                    variant.correct = result["correct"] as? Int
                    self.Variants.append(variant)
                }

            }

        }
        }.resume()
```

Comment: `resultA` is an array of arrays of dictionaries.

Comment: @maddy and what ?

Comment: Your code assumes it's an array of dictionaries. It's not. It's an array of arrays of dictionaries. Update your code accordingly.

Comment: var resultA = resultsAnswer[0]; try and print.

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL now my resultAnswer is empty. it is printing error I can not got access to resultA

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL I guess that my mistake is in this :                                              as? [[String: AnyObject]]   do you now how to write this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following should work

```
if let resultsAnswer = jsons["resultA"] as? [[[String: AnyObject]]] {
        print("got Result", resultsAnswer)
        self.Variants = []
        for resultList in resultsAnswer {
            for result in resultList {
                let variant = Variant()
                variant.title = result["title"] as? String
                variant.correct = result["correct"] as? Int
                self.Variants.append(variant)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: now how can I identify the amount of elements that was in each array (resultA[0],resultA[1])??? For example identify that in resultA[0] is 2 elements, in resultA[1] is 3 elements, please help )))))

Comment: You can get that by checking *resultList.count*. This will be the elements inside the resultA[0] etc..